# An unique function or infinitely many ?

Tags: taylor-expansion

Suppose I have the following conditions:

$f(0)=a$

$f'(0)=b$

$f''(0)=c$

...

$f^{\infty'}(0)= $  something

Is there an unique $f(x)$ which satisfies this?

In other words: given the values of some function and all of its derivatives at  point $a$, and given the function is infinitely differentiable, only one function exists that satisfies them?

Answer (score 3):

No.  There are $C^\infty$ ["bump functions"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function).

To get uniqueness, you'll want to assume the function is analytic.